# LDR circuit does not change sound frequency

Tags: arduino, ldr

I am a complete beginner in the field of electrical engineering. In the Arduino cookbook, there is this circuit:

[image]

I have been trying to reproduce it, and I do hear a sound after uploading the software, but it does not change at all regardless of the light intensity. I think I got buildup right, but I did not have a 4.7k resistor, so I used one with 3.3k (problem here?).

Here is a schematic of how I put the lower part together (I assume the upper part is not the problem, otherwise I probably would not be hearing anything); please excuse my poor drawing skills.

[image: schematic]

I would appreciate a hint on why this is not working as expected. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To separate possible causes... do you have a potentiometer? A 5 kohm or higher pot will do. Remove your breadboard, and connect the pot so that its two ends go to GND and +5 V, and the wiper goes to "Analog 0". Use exactly the same firmware, and the same speaker. If the sound changes when you turn the potentiometer, there's something wrong with your LDR, or with your breadboard setup. If the sound does not change, the fault is in the firmware or speaker.

Comment: @Telaclavo Thanks, I did exactly what you suggested with a 10k potentiometer. The sound does change using that. I've replaced the LDR with another one to check if the one I used is broken, but that did not change anything. So apparently I have something wrong in my breadboard setup?

Comment: 2nd experiment: do you have a multimeter? If so, connect the LDR directly to it, configured as an ohm-meter. Check that the resistance measured does change, when you illuminate it or not.

Comment: @Telaclavo I have done that, now. If I set the multimeter to 2000k Ohm, it will display 250 from the light in my room, and about 700-800 if I cover it up.

Comment: Then, you need to increment your resistor from 3.3 kohm to something in the range {220 kohm ... 680 kohm}, if you have, to notice a larger variation in voltage (frequency).

Comment: @Telaclavo Great. I've replaced the 3.3k with a 560k resistor and it is working now! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Kudos @Telaclavo for helping OP interactively. You could have posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as a generic LDR. They're available in a wide range of resistances. [This one](http://www.advancedphotonix.com/ap_products/pdfs/PDV-P9203.pdf) varies from 30k\$\Omega\$ to 5M\$\Omega\$, while [this one](http://www.advancedphotonix.com/ap_products/pdfs/PDV-P8101.pdf) varies between 11k\$\Omega\$ and 150k\$\Omega\$. They will give you a completely different output range, which the software may or not may detect properly.

The first one will give a voltage between 3mV and 0.5V. If you have an LDR like this the output voltage may be too low.
The second one, on the other hand, will give you a voltage between 0.1V and 1.15V, which is already a bit better. A 4.7k\$\Omega\$ resistor will raise this to 1.5V.